# Showing same task on different category

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone tell me why all tasks are showing in different category?

I created a new category and add a task. However, when I check the task list, it shows all the tasks from other category.

I just `<%= render 'tasks/form' %>` do this in my category show

This is my form in tasks -> _task.html.erb

```rb
<div>
<h1> Add Task </h1>
<%= form_with model: [@categories, @categories.tasks.build]  do |form|%>
  <%=form.label :task_name %> 
  <%=form.text_field :taskname %>
  <%=form.label :body %>
  <%=form.text_field :body %>
  <%=form.label :time %>
  <%=form.text_field :time %
  <br>
  <br>
  <%=form.submit "Submit" %>
<%end%>
</div>
```

CategoryController:

```rb
def show
  @categories = Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

Please let met know what I need to check thank you.

Comment: When you say 'check the task list', can you add the code where you are doing that to your question?

Comment: Its just when i go to the task#index . all of tasks are there for all category id . I thought if i create task in category 1 , it should not show up in category 2 task#index .

Comment: Gotta show the code, mate. The problem is task#index but you’ve included code for completely different things (adding a task, loading a category). If the problem is tasks getting loaded wrongly, just add the code where you are loading the tasks for the index page.

Comment: <body id="task-details-body">
<h1 style="background-color:purple;color:white;height:100px;padding:20px;padding-bottom:10px;"> Task Details </h1>
<br>
<div>;
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <div class = "task-details">
        <h1><%= task.taskname %></h1>
        <h3><%= task.body %></h3>
        <h5><%= task.time %></h5>
        <%= link_to 'View',category_task_path(task.category_id,task.id) %>
        <%= link_to ' Add new Task' , category_path(task.category_id)%>
    </div>
<%end%>

</div>
</body>

Comment: When asked for additional information please respond by editing your question and not by commenting. Readers should be able to understand the entire question by reading the question body. You also have an inconsistency in this code - `:task_name` and `:taskname`.

Comment: Ugh, I'm weirdly invested in this now. You view is just showing all tasks in `@tasks`, so your actual question is "how is `@tasks` ending up with all those extra tasks"? A good thing to do would be to look at the controller method (i.e., `TasksController#index`) where you are setting `@tasks`. Edit your question and add that code and all will be revealed.